# I am trying to get a json from the following code but I am getting response header(in screenshot)

Tags: android, json, connection

I want a JSON but I am getting a response header. I am using Android Studio 2.1.1. I am using the `OkHttpClient` library and `AsyncTask` to separate it from the main thread.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        new PostTask().execute("url");

    }

    private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];

            // Dummy code
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // connect timeout
            client.setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);    // socket timeout

            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "data=something");
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .addHeader("postman-token", "7a4d5df8-5aed-19bf-e1fb-c85f821c1d10")
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .build();
            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.toString();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
This is the screenshot of the response.

Comment: Did you try to run your url in normal browser? What exactly it shows?

Comment: @naran z I got it solved...Thanx for your interest....FYI the browser showed ---> {"status":0,"msg":"Error:Unknown http method is used for request!"}

Answer (score 1):

You need to request the body.

Instead of use:

```
return response.toString();
```

Use:

```
return response.body().string();
```

that sould return the body content.

NOTE:
*.toString() method return the object string.*

Here you have an example from documentation: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```